# runpath not in xcode settings

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am having a lot of issues with `cocoapods` where, doing `pod install` installs the correct library / framework. And I can reference it in code. However, during compile time, I get linker errors, where even I reference the pod frameworks. If I manually add the frameworks, things sometimes work. I believe there is an inherit issue, within my project settings and for the life of me cannot figure it out.

I started a new project, and added pods I needed, and everything worked fine, without having to manually add anything. So its definitely something in the project settings I think.

I did notice, on the new project I have the following, under the project target: Runpath Search Path. Which is under Linking.

This however, is not in my main project and I am not sure how I go about adding it to the project?

Other than that... I am stumped as to where else to look to fixing these issues.